# Verification of my thought process for the ordering of "there exists" and "for all"

Tags: logic

How many of the 8 combinations of  $\forall$ or $\exists$ can fill in the following parenthesis such that the statement be true for
$x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$?:

($\text{__}$)$x$ ($\text{__}$)$y$ ($\text{__}$)$z, x<y+z$

**My thoughts:** The only requirement for the statement to be true is that there be a " $\exists$ " before the $z$ so $z$ can depend on $x$ and $y$: Let $z=-y+x-1$ so the statement holds for any $x$. To me, there *appears* no way the statement is true if there's a " $\forall$ " in front of the $z$. This means the answer is **4**

*side question (**solved** by @DavidP):* Why when I try to put "__" inside the parenthesis, it *sometimes* disappears and screws with the format?

Comment: This depends on the domain of your variables. For example $\exists x \forall y \forall z$ works if $x,y,z\in\mathbb N$. For your side question, using "_" in latex gives a subscript, so best to avoid that, or use \text{}

Comment: @DavidP $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$